# prevent the regular tab-key function onkeyup

Tags: javascript, onkeyup

I have about 20 small dropdowns in row. Each of those have two javascript functions.

- `onchange`: call an ajax function for saving the value
- `onkeyup`: jump to the next dropdown and open it

Now if the user press tab, the next dropdown will be omitted. This is why I want to prevent the regular tab-key function.
How to do this?

Comment: Did you try to check key code on keydown and preventDefault if it's tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can call such a method :

```
function keyHandler(e) {
    var TABKEY = 9;
    if(e.keyCode == TABKEY) {
        if(e.preventDefault) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this code might help you

```
$("your-selector").on('keyup', function(e) { 
    if (e.keyCode == 9) { // <- here confirm that tab is pressed.
       e.preventDefault(); // <- Prevent defaul functionality of tab.
       // your code if tab pressed.
    }
    // code if its not a tab key.
});
```